# nuget: dll is not inside lib folder

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to create a nuget package that depends on a custom .dll. For that, I use this code:

```
NuGet_v5.2.0.exe pack Cmon.csproj -Prop Configuration=Release -IncludeReferencedProjects
```

I am greeted with:

```
WARNING: NU5100: The assembly 'content\lib\Request32\libcurl.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
```

For every dll I depend on. Apperently, `lib` under which I put Request32 and Request64 is not the one nuget looks for. Where should I put my dll dependencies? This is my folder structure printer with `tree /F .` command:

```
│   Cmon.csproj
│   Cmon.nuspec
│   nuget.exe
│   nuget_v5.2.0.exe
│   packages.config
│
├───bin
│   ├───Debug
│   │   │   Cmon.dll
│   │   │   Cmon.pdb
│   │   │   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│   │   │   Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│   │   │   System.IO.dll
│   │   │   System.Runtime.dll
│   │   │
│   │   └───lib
│   │       ├───Request32
│   │       │       libcurl.dll
│   │       │       Request32.dll
│   │       │       zlib1.dll
│   │       │
│   │       └───Request64
│   │               libcurl.dll
│   │               Request64.dll
│   │               zlib1.dll
│   │
│   └───Release
│       │   Cmon.dll
│       │   Cmon.pdb
│       │   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
│       │   Newtonsoft.Json.xml
│       │   System.IO.dll
│       │   System.Runtime.dll
│       │
│       └───lib
│           ├───Request32
│           │       libcurl.dll
│           │       Request32.dll
│           │       zlib1.dll
│           │
│           └───Request64
│                   libcurl.dll
│                   Request64.dll
│                   zlib1.dll
│
├───Conf
│       Access.cs
│
├───EMessage
│       EMessage.cs
│
├───lib
│   ├───Request32
│   │       libcurl.dll
│   │       Request32.dll
│   │       zlib1.dll
│   │
│   └───Request64
│           libcurl.dll
│           Request64.dll
│           zlib1.dll
│
├───obj
│   ├───Debug
│   │   │   Cmon.csproj.CopyComplete
│   │   │   Cmon.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
│   │   │   Cmon.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
│   │   │   Cmon.dll
│   │   │   Cmon.pdb
│   │   │
│   │   └───TempPE
│   └───Release
│       │   Cmon.csproj.CopyComplete
│       │   Cmon.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
│       │   Cmon.csprojAssemblyReference.cache
│       │   Cmon.dll
│       │   Cmon.pdb
│       │
│       └───TempPE
└───Properties
        AssemblyInfo.cs
```

Cmon.nuspec content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <description>Cmon Code</description>
    <copyright>Copyright 2021</copyright>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Have you checked the DLL is physically where it is supposed to be? I mean if it really exists on the storage. Sometimes it happens that the file is referenced but is not actually available on the storage.

Comment: @MostafaF.Rad the files are indeed in lib fodler.

Comment: Try NugetPackageExplorer GUI. It will give you a visual hint of your package. Compare the nusepc it makes to your manual one.